# How to read and view a disc file in a webix application

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, webix

I am absolutely new into webix development and not finding much documentation/help about my current challenge.

In my webix application, I want to have button (name say 'View Report') clicking which will link to a disc file in my local disc and show its content in a popup window.

I am including the snippet of code which I could write so far :

```
mytoolbar =
  {             id:'tb',
                view: 'toolbar',
                height: rowHeight,
                type: 'clean',
                cols: [
{view:"button", id:"showfile",  type:"icon", icon:"external-link", label:"View Report", width:buttonWidth, tooltip: "click to view report", on: {onItemClick:function(){viewReportFile()}} },

]
```

And the viewReportFile function looks as below (taken from 
http://docs.webix.com/desktop__window.html )

```
function viewReportFile(){
     webix.ui( {
        view:"window",
        height:250,
        width:300,
        left:50, top:50,
        move:true,
        resize: true,
        head:"This window can be resized",
        body:{
            template:"Some text"
        }
    }).show();    

})      
}
```

Clicking the button should read a file residing in my directory (lets say at C:\Users\myname\Desktop\report.txt") and display that file content in the modal window. It could be any popup window to display the file content with a close button. Can anybody help me with the implementation ? I apologize for not being able to put much code here as I am new to it.

I am also including an working code which lets the user pick a file from his directory and shows its content in the textarea.

```
<html>

<input type="file" onchange="onFileSelected(event)">
<br>
<textarea id="result" rows="10" cols="50"></textarea>
<script>
function onFileSelected(event) {
  var selectedFile = event.target.files[0];
  var reader = new FileReader();

  var result = document.getElementById("result");

  reader.onload = function(event) {
    result.innerHTML = event.target.result;
  };

  reader.readAsText(selectedFile);
}

</script>
</html>
```

Thanks.

Comment: Webix is a User Interface framework. It can load data from JSON or XML file using ajax request. For the rest you have to write your own code to load data into webix components.

Comment: @fabien-michel Thanks for your reply. Just now I have edited the question to add an working example of my requirement. Could you please help me with how can I use  or fit in that code when implementing in webix ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here a sample, but keep in mind that there is many way to perform this and this sample shouldn't be best suited for your specific case :

http://webix.com/snippet/36341f3c

```
function loadReport() {
  return "My report string";
}

function viewReportFile() {
  $$('myContent').define('template', loadReport());
  $$('myPopup').show();
}


webix.ui({
        id: 'myPopup',
        view:"window",
        height:250,
        width:300,
        left:50,
        top:50,
        move:true,
        resize: true,
        head:"This window can be resized",
        body:{
            id: 'myContent',
            template: "Some text"
        }
    });
```